# Using TEI XML parser in a loop

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I found [this](https://komax.github.io/blog/text/python/xml/parsing_tei_xml_python/) article on parsing TEI XML very helpful when dealing with single XML files. However, I have an entire directory. My loop through the dir is not executing and I do not know why.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os.path
import glob

tei_docs = "../input/tei-xml-files"
    def read_tei(tei_docs):
    os.chdir(tei_docs)
for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(tei_docs, "*.xml")):
    read_file(i)
```

`def read_file(i):`

```
with open(i, "r") as tei:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(tei, 'lxml')
```

`soup.title.getText()`

I get the output

NameError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

----> 1 soup.title.getText()

NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code, including indentation mistakes. I also wrote a script to read titles from XML files with Beautiful Soup that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from os.path import dirname, join
directory=("C:\\Users\\mbarg\\Documents\\corpus") # location of XML files on local drive

results=[] # create result list
for infile in os.listdir(directory):
    filename=join(directory, infile)
    indata=open(filename,"r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") # UTF-8 encoding errors are ignored
    contents = indata.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
    titles = soup.find_all('title') # get item titles
    for title in titles:
        print(title.get_text())
        results.append(title.get_text())
print(results) # result list is shown on screen
```